# MDT Server opens cmdlet directly

Tags: virtual-machine, mdt, wds

As the title already mentions, the MDT Server opens the cmdlet directly after loading the Lite Touch Windows PE image. I added a few arguments in the CustomSettings.ini.

I am running a ESXi 6.7 Server where the MDT-Server is installed. And new VM's should be able to be deployed via MDT.

```
[Settings]
Priority=Default, VM, Laptop, Desktop
Properties=MyCustomProperty

[...]

[VM]
Subsection=VM-%IsVM%

[Laptop]
Subsection=Laptop-%IsLaptop%

[Desktop]
Subsection=Desktop-%IsDesktop%

[VM-True]
OSDComputername=VM-#right("%UUID%",6)#

[Laptop-True]
OSDComputername=NB-#right("%UUID%",6)#

[Desktop-True]
OSDComputername=PC-#right("%UUID%",6)#
```

So, I added those lines and after trying to deploy a VM it opened directly the CMDLET. I also removed it again and it still doesn't work. So I'm wondering why the MDT is making such a mess right now. The reason why I did this is, I wanted MDT to set the "OSDComputerName" automatically. I also researched how to set the ComputerName with Variables such as "%03#". This did also opened the CMDLET directly after loading the image.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of reconfiguring the CustomSettings.ini, I deleted and created a new vmdk, restarted the VM and et voilá it works again!